# Find all $q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{q(q+1)}{12}$ is a Perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, quadratics, pell-type-equations

Find all $q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{q(q+1)}{12}$ is a Perfect square.

Trivially we see that $q=3$ is the first candidate.
Now let $$\frac{q(q+1)}{12}=r^2$$
$\implies$
$$q^2+q-12r^2=0$$
By Quadratic formula we get
$$q=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{48r^2+1}}{2}$$
Any help here?

Comment: You correctly tagged this [tag:pell-type-equations]; it's $(2q+1)^2-3(4r)^2=1$

Comment: To start, you need q to be even, so that you can divide by 2, and the discriminant to be a natural number, which means you can factor the polynomial in your question.

Comment: Isn't it the same as $\dfrac{q(q+1)}3$ being a perfect square?

Answer (score 4):

It remains to find $r$ such that $48r^2+1=s^2$ or $s^2-48r^2=1$, which is Pell's equation with fundamental solution $s=7,r=1,q=3$ as you found. All other solutions are generated by the following recurrence:
$$\begin{bmatrix}s_{k+1}\\r_{k+1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}7&48\\1&7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}s_k\\r_k\end{bmatrix}$$
This may be solved for $s=\sqrt{48r^2+1}$, giving
$$s=\frac{(7+4\sqrt3)^k+(7-4\sqrt3)^k}2,k\in\mathbb N$$
Since we want only positive $q$, we take the positive sign in the formula for $q$, yielding $q=\frac{s-1}2$.

Comment: also $s_{k+2}  = 14 s_{k+1}  - s_k, \; \; \; \; \; $   $r_{k+2}  = 14 r_{k+1}  - r_k, \; \; \; \; \; $

Answer (score 1):

You correctly tagged this [pell-type-equations](/questions/tagged/pell-type-equations).

Note that $\dfrac{q^2+q}{12}=r^2\iff (2q+1)^2-3(4r)^2=1$, which I got by completing the square.

You also have the first solution correct:  $q=3$ and $r=1$.

As is known for Pell-type equations,

the other solutions are of the form $(2q+1)+\sqrt3 (4r)=(7+4\sqrt3)^n$,

for $n=2,3,4,5,...$.

The solutions for $q$ can be found in [OEIS here](https://oeis.org/A007654).